# Are synchronization constructs required for multiple fork() calls?

Tags: synchronization, fork, wait

Looking over examples of the fork() function, I am unsure when and when not to use the wait() call. I assume the wait() call isn't really ever needed and is used as more of an error-handling tool in case a parent processes spawns too many children processes.However, I am not really sure and any clarification on the subject matter would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the wait() call isn't really ever needed and is used as more
>   of an error-handling tool

Not really.

wait system calls are needed when parent process needs to know when the child process finish.

e.g. In one of my project I had a requirement to allow running parallel *n* sub tasks at a time. What I did was spawn a subtask using the fork. Then spawn a thread which did the waitpid to wait for the completion of the spawned subtask to regulate the flow of parallel *n* sub tasks.

You can check [here](https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/03/21/task-scheduler/) how the fork and waitpid were used to satisfy the task scheduler constraint.